The uniqueness of a solution Impossible chessboard puzzle
I found a video about a famous puzzle called  "Almost imopossible chessboard puzzle"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=as7Gkm7Y7h4
and a website that shows us a lot of solutions of it.
https://www.cantorsparadise.com/a-fascinating-prisoners-puzzle-be874032f43e
Now I'm wondering if all the solutions are essentially equivalent.
If they are, could you give me a proof?
To be precise, let me describe the problem.
Let $n$ be a power of  2 and $f:\{0,1\}^n\rightarrow \{0,\cdots n\}$ is a function such that for any $x\in \{0,1\}^n$ and $a\in \{0,\cdots, n\}$, there exists $x'\in \{0,1\}^n$ s.t $x$ and $x'$ have same component except one component and $f(x')=a$
My question is if $g:\{0,1\}^n\rightarrow \{0,\cdots n\}$  has the same property, then are there bijections $\phi:\{0,1\}^n\rightarrow \{0,1\}^n$ and $\psi:\{0,\cdots n\}\rightarrow \{0,\cdots n\}$ s.t $f=\psi\circ g\circ\phi$?
Here $\phi$ should have the property that if $x$ and $x'$ have same components except one,
$\phi(x)$ and $\phi(x')$ have same components except one.

Yes, any two strategies are equivalent in the sense you mention.
As Grant Sanderson explains in the video, when thinking about the puzzle in terms of colouring the vertices of an $n$-cube, the vertices must be evenly divided among the different colours, which implies that $n$ must divide $2^n$, i.e. be a power of $2$, say $n = 2^m$. In the language of your question, this means that the fibres of $f$ and $g$ must all have the same cardinality: $\forall x \in [n]. f^{-1}(x) \simeq [2^{n - m}] \simeq g^{-1}(x)$. These fibrewise isomorphisms assemble into an isomorphism $\phi : [2^n] \simeq [2^n]$ such that $f = g \circ \phi$ (note that we don't need to reorder the codomain since all the fibres are isomorphic).

Does this bijection preserve connection?

i.e two neighboring points x and x' maps to two neighboring points?
